# Is it possible to delete or lower the permissions of the current account?

Tags: user-account, administrator

Exactly what the title says.  I would love to know if you can fully delete or lower the permissions of an admin account that is currently in use (from aforementioned account).  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific? IE: do you wish to convert an admin account into a "standard account" with the accompanying privileges?

Answer (score 2):

No - admin users or not, you can't delete the logged in user using the system preferences panel.

You can remove admin permissions, but until all processes get killed (logging out will also work), the running processes are still privileged.

Answer (score 2):

You can lower the privileges of the current user using the parental controls.

[image]

You can find the details [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14414)

In one of the tabs you can activate this for the current account,

Comment: This is incorrect. 1) Admin users are not even eligible to show up in Parental Controls - whether they are logged in or not. 2) Parental controls don't necessarily take effect until the user logs out and logs in again.